# Insert images in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I need to insert images to excel, below code inserts only last image for all cell in excel, instead of insert for each cell different images.
This code for each iteration creates different (wright) jpg files (overwriting on each iteration), but insert in excel last jpg fail.
Can you help me?

```
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['PP']
image_row=0
image_col=4
for image in image_src:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, "image.jpg")
    worksheet.insert_image(image_row,
                    image_col,
                    'image.jpg',
                    {'x_scale':0.5,'y_scale':0.5,
                     'x_offset':5,'y_offset':5,
                     'positioning':1})
    image_row +=1
```

Comment: I think it could be that you insert a reference of the image in the excel file, each time the file `image.jpg` is being overwritten and the last remains. Try saving the file with a different name each time and insert the unique name to the excel file.

Comment: @zerofuxor - I think it would be solution, but there would be a lot of images to save and i wanted to get rid of to save many images. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at xlwings.

xlwings documentation: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html

Adding a picture to sheet:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
sht = wb.sheets[0]
sht.pictures.add(r'C:\path\to\file.jpg')
```

You can also specify, top, bottom, left, right of cells like so:

```
sht.pictures.add(r'C:\path\to\file.jpg', name='picture1', left=sht.range("A1").left, top=sht.range("A2").top)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nishan Pradhan - i wrote below code, but it inserts only one picture twice.
itteration dose not go on (it stops on second iteration, with error "ShapeAlreadyExists").

```
wb = xw.Book()
sht = wb.sheets[0]


image_row=2

for image in image_src:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, "image.jpg")
    sht.pictures.add(r'C:\path\to\image.jpg', name='image.jpg', left=sht.range("E"+str(image_row)).left, top=sht.range("E"+str(image_row+1)).top)
    image_row +=1
```

Comment: Apologies, its been a year but for anyone else, you probably need to change the `name='image.jpg'` so that Excel sees it as a different image and doesn't overwrite it. So perhaps increment the name so `name='image1'`, `name='image2'` etc.